# How to generate push notifications after every 1 min from azure

Tags: c#, azure, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I am working on an window 8 app where I have to create some tasks in the exchange server. I am able to implement this logic through my azure services. the tasks contains a reminder field to set reminders.

I want to implement the feature of showing notifications of reminder to the user in my app. But the problem is that when I have implemented the SchedulerAgent in it it runs after every 15 mins duration. So in many cases the reminders don't fell in the condition and not able to get the reminders notification.

So I am trying to send some push notifications after every 1 minute to my app. So that it just makes the background scheduler work and show the reminders if they are available from my local db.

How can I implement the task to run a timer like thing that could probably push notifications after every minute to my app regularly so that I never miss out a reminder notification.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use SignalR:

http://signalr.net/